# How to start python simpleHTTPServer on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, simplehttpserver

I recently bought a Windows 10 machine and now I want to run a server locally for testing a webpage I am developing.

On Windows 7 it was always very simple to start a HTTP Server via python and the command prompt. Fx writing the below code would fire up a HTTP server and I could watch the website through localhost.

> C:\pathToIndexfile\python -m SimpleHTTPServer

This does however not seems to work on Windows 10...

Does anyone know how to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: Alternative Server Options as well: [Extremely simple web server for Windows](https://superuser.com/q/231080/180163)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so different commands is apparently needed.

This works:

> C:\pathToIndexfile\py -m http.server

*As pointed out in a comment, the change to "http.server" is not because of windows, but because I changed from python 2 to python 3.*

Comment: Note that the change from `SimpleHTTPServer` to `http.server` is because you have switched from Python 2 to 3. It is unrelated to the Windows version.

Answer (score 6):

If you already have `python 3` installed, just run:

```
python -m http.server
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, neither `python` nor `python3` worked for me; the program just hangs there, doing nothing.

However, I got it to work via `ipython`:

```
ipython -m http.server 8000
```

You need to install IPython beforehand, though:

```
pip install ipython
```

Comment: after you run the command from the comment above 'python -m http.server'  
It starts the server.  
  
`Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...   ::1 - - [18/Nov/2020 10:34:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -   ::1 - - [18/Nov/2020 10:34:15] code 404, message File not found  
::1 - - [18/Nov/2020 10:34:15] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - ` 
  
After that, you have to open a browser and go to 'localhost:8000'